SwiftUI TabView how can it can split the content in multiple views?
I'm trying to reverse engineer how the TabView initializer works.
public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

We know that if we write something like this:
TabView {
        Text("Placeholder_1")
        Text("Placeholder_2")
    }

It creates a container view with 2 tabs, so it seems that on the inside the TabView is able to understand that we are sending a TupleView composed by 2 views and put each one in a specific one.
I'd like to build something similar but I do not understand how I can detect how many elements are in the TupleView and separate them.
I already read this but it seems that we must know in advance how many elements are composing the TupleView while I'd like to keep them as generic as possibile as it happens in the TabView.
Is SwiftUI using some sort of introspection?

In iOS 18 you can use ViewBuilder and ForEach there is a private API varadic view for iOS 17. There is also SwiftUI.Layout. Access to individual views is very limited

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10146

Thx @loremipsum I already saw the private API but I don't think it is good for production. The only solution seems to be create many init with a good amount of element in a touple

Thx @malhal unfortunately just iOS18, no backwards compatibility

Well what do you want then? You don't want to use what SwiftUI internally uses before iOS 18, and you don't want iOS 18 API. There is no magic.
